# When playing an RTSP stream with exoplayer, an IllegalStateException exception occurs

Tags: java, android, exception, rtsp, exoplayer

When using exoplayer to play an RTSP stream, and then disconnecting the network or interrupting the RTSP stream, the checkStateNotNull exception will be randomly reported; Version: media3-exoplayer:1.1.1; The details are as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Playback
Process: com.join.driving, PID: 28548
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at androidx.media3.common.util.Assertions.checkStateNotNull(Assertions.java:117)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMessageChannel.send(RtspMessageChannel.java:190)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspClient$MessageSender.sendRequest(RtspClient.java:481)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspClient$MessageSender.sendSetupRequest(RtspClient.java:380)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspClient.continueSetupRtspTrack(RtspClient.java:296)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspClient.setupSelectedTracks(RtspClient.java:221)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod.maybeSetupTracks(RtspMediaPeriod.java:478)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod.access$2600(RtspMediaPeriod.java:66)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod$RtpLoadInfo.lambda$new$0$androidx-media3-exoplayer-rtsp-RtspMediaPeriod$RtpLoadInfo(RtspMediaPeriod.java:893)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod$RtpLoadInfo$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onTransportReady(Unknown Source:2)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtpDataLoadable.lambda$load$0$androidx-media3-exoplayer-rtsp-RtpDataLoadable(RtpDataLoadable.java:158)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtpDataLoadable$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Can this exception be caught with a try catch, or how can it be avoided?

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace none of your app code is involved, thus catching is not possible. BTW: you forgot to mention the used exoplayer version.